# How to download specific files type from google drive folder

Tags: google-drive

Say I have different types of files in a google drive folder like documents, pdf, images etc. I need to download all documents from the drive filder. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google takeout (select PDF as desired format)

https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout

Or

Use https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#exporting-docs